# avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 arduino

Tags: arduino

I have looked at many questions with this title, but I cannot find any solutions.
I am getting this error:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync(): not in sync: resp=0x00 arduino
```

Normally when I encounter this error, I change the Arduino to another USB port or restart the IDE, and everything is solved.

But when I plugged my Arduino Uno in to my computer this morning, I was surprised to see this error right away.  When I attempt to send code to the Arduino, the RX pin blinks a few times, but no TX.  To troubleshoot, I tried shorting the RX and TX pins, and when I open the serial monitor (which still works), I get exactly what I send, so I know my TX is working.
I have tried this Arduino with other computers, and it still gives the same result.

Another thing - the computer sees the Arduino as com34. It does not change even if I change the port number of the USB. My Arduino worked normally until this morning.

I am stuck!  What are the possible reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that no wire is going to pin 0 (RX) while you're doing the sketch upload?
That solution worked for me.